# document.getElementById("remember").visibility = "hidden"; not working on a checkbox

Tags: javascript, visibility

I cannot get the `visibility` or `display` properties to work.

Here is the HTML footer:

```
<div id="footer">
  &copy; 
  <strong id="foot" onmouseover="showData();" onmouseout = "hideData()">
    Exquisite Taste 2012
  </strong>
  <input type='checkbox' id="remember" onclick='editCookie()' style="visibility:hidden;" />
</div>
```

Here is the .js function with the visibility part not working:

```
function showData()
{


  document.getElementById("remember").visiblity="visible";


  document.getElementById("foot").innerHTML = getDate() + "  " + getTime();

  if(cookieValue())
  {
    document.getElementById("remember").checked = true;
  }
}
```

That one line doesn't seem to do anything:

```
document.getElementById("remember").visiblity="visible";
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

- The property is called `visibility` and not `visiblity`.
- It is not a property of the element itself but of its `.style` property.

It's easy to fix. Simple replace this:

```
document.getElementById("remember").visiblity
```

with this:

```
document.getElementById("remember").style.visibility
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 18):

This is the job for `style` property:

```
document.getElementById("remember").style.visibility = "visible";
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use

```
style="display:none"
```

Ex:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txbProv" runat="server" style="display:none"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: The `display:none` setting permanently removes that item from the dom, and thus fails the poster's requirement to toggle on/off. `visibility` is the correct way to handle this.